# How do I print multiple authors correctly using BibTeX bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, formatting

So I've been looking for an answer to my question on here for quite some time now, but nobody seems to be having the same problem as me:

I'm using BibTeX and my makefile does `latex` `latex` `bibtex` `latex` `pdflatex` on the file.

In my `refs.bib` file I have

```
@book{NISTCloudComputing,
  title = {The NIST Definition of Cloud Computing},
  author = {Peter Mell and Timothy Grance},
  year = {2011},
  publisher = {National Institute of Standards and Technology},
  url = {http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-145.pdf},
  urldate = {2016-03-07}
}
```

and then over in my tex file I'm printing the bibliography at the bottom using `\printbibliography[maxnames=100]` along with all this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\nocite{*}
```

as well as a couple of extra bits to reformat the output of the bibliography:

```
\NewBibliographyString{available}
\NewBibliographyString{accessed}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  available = {available at},
  accessed = {Accessed},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{available}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\space(\bibstring{accessed}\addcolon\space#1)}
```

The output of this reference shows:

Mell, Peter and Timothy Grance (2011). The NIST Definition of Cloud Computing.
National Institute of Standards and Technology. Available at:
http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-
145.pdf (Accessed: 03/07/2016).

Now my question is, why is the first name split up wrong, showing "Last, First" and then the second name is shown correctly?

Comment: The sorting is by the last name of the first author, and so his last name is shown first to help finding the entries. If you don't like this search for "biblatex last-first" to find examples how to change the name formats.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I just found it weird as I read this as if the three Grance brothers wrote the book, I've changed it to use last-first now and it looks better, thanks for commenting :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comment.